# jquery load() strips script tags - workaround?

Tags: jquery, tags, load

Does anyone know of a work around for jquery .load() stripping out the script tags loaded from external content?

There's a lot of documentation of the fact that this happens but after something like 4 hours searching the net I can't find a work around?

I'm loading dynamically generated divs - similar to a page of search results - and need to bind a .click() to an element within each dynamically generated div. I've a php file that does the html generation work and returns all the html as a string however I can't bind the jquery .click() as the script tags containing the jquery function get stripped out.

here's the code that loads the external content by calling the php file...

```
$("#titles_wrap").load("m_scripts/m_php/titles_loader.php", function(){
                                                                $..some code
                                                                });
```

and here's the loop from the php file that generates the divs (this works fine)...

```
$tag1='<script type="text/javascript">';
$tag2='</script>';

while($result_array = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            if($i2<=($titles_total)){

                $_SESSION['titles_string'] .= '<li id="listItem_'.$i2.'">

                                                <div id="titles_list_item">

                                                    <div id="titles_list_image_box" style="background-image: url(../../images/thumbs_test/'.$result_array[0].'); background-repeat: no-repeat; ">'.($i2+1).'</div>
                                                    <div id="title_php_loader"></div>
                                                        <div id="title_info_wrap">

                                                        <div id="title_current"><span class="title_current_grey" >current title: </span><br>'.$result_array[1].'
                                                            </div>

                                                                <div id="title_form_wrap">
                                                                    <span class="title_current_grey" >new title: </span><br><input name="title_input_'.$i2.'" id="title_input_'.$i2.'" type="text" class="title_input"></input>
                                                                    <div id="title_send" class="title_send_'.$i2.'">GO</div>
                                                                </div>

                                                            </div>


                                                    '.$tag1.'
                                                    $(".title_send_'.$i2.'").click(function(){$("#title_php_loader").load("m_scripts/m_php/title_sender.php")})
                                                    '.$tag2.'

                                                </div>
                                            </li>';
                $i2++;
                                }
            }
```

Sorry if this second code block is a bit on the 'overkill' side - let me know if a simplified excerpt would be more useful. That said, you can see on the 8th from last line of the php code the jquery function that should get written into each div with a dynamically assigned selector.

Of course, it could be that there's other errors in the code however I'm not going to be able to test it until I can get .load() to stop trashing it!

If anyone's found a solution to this - or even a workaround of limited grace - brilliant!

Thanks in advance,

Cheers,

Scott

**EDIT - EDIT - EDIT - EDIT - EDIT - EDIT - EDIT - EDIT**

@T.J. Crowder 
@Frug

Thanks for your help!

I've just had a good hard look at the pages involved in your demo and yes, I see you've got it working. Seems amazing cos there they are - those script tags and there are SO many people out there who can't get it to work - unfortunately I'm one of them!

The only differences I see between your demo and my code situation was

1) no type declaration in the opening script tag,

2) you're loading a page with script tags as part of the DOM, whereas I was loading php string output (I really don't think this matters tho', eh? By the time it hits the client it all comes to the same thing, no?)

3), your .load call was fetching a whole page whereas mine was returning only elements. I've since changed the output string to include all ,  and  tags but grrrrrr...I still can't get dem damn script tags to show up in the DOM.

Any suggestions? There's loads I don't know about so could be anything! thanks S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery `load` ***doesn't*** strip out script tags ([example](http://jsbin.com/esobe5)), and there are no script tags in the content you're returning from your PHP script. There is some JavaScript, but it's not correctly embedded in `script` tags and so it's not being recognized by the browser.

If you want the JavaScript in this:

```
...
'.$tag1.'
$(".title_send_'.$i2.'").click(function(){$("#title_php_loader").load("m_scripts/m_php/title_sender.php")})
'.$tag2.'
...
```

to be recognized as JavaScript, put it in a `script` tag.

```
...
'.$tag1.'
<script>"$(".title_send_'.$i2.'").click(function(){$("#title_php_loader").load("m_scripts/m_php/title_sender.php")})</script>
'.$tag2.'
...
```

...or better yet, use a single `script` tag at the end of the content to hook things up, or the callback on the [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load) function.

---

**Update**: Re your edit:

> 1) no type declaration in the opening script tag,

Doesn't matter, see [this updated example](http://jsbin.com/esobe5/2). The browser interprets the `script` tag according to the same rules it always applies.

> 2) you're loading a page with script tags as part of the DOM, whereas I was loading php string output (I really don't think this matters tho', eh? By the time it hits the client it all comes to the same thing, no?)

Right, it all comes to the same thing once it gets to the browser.

> 3), your .load call was fetching a whole page whereas mine was returning only elements. I've since changed the output string to include all , and tags but grrrrrr...I still can't get dem damn script tags to show up in the DOM.

My example is just loading a snippet, not a full page.

I don't know why yours isn't working. I wondered if it related to multiple script elements being output in a loop, or the fact you were hooking up a `click` handler, but [it's not either of those](http://jsbin.com/esobe5/3).

There's nothing for it but to take your non-working example and peel layers away bit by bit until you find the part that, when you remove it, lets it start working. Fundamentally, again, it's **not** that using `load` makes the scripts not work (regardless of how many people you find who think that's the case; it's a big world, there are lots of people who think nearly anything). You have to let go of the idea that this is related to jQuery's `load` function doing anything to the scripts; it probably isn't.

The key to debugging this kind of thing really is *simplify, simplify, simplify*. make sure the HTML being returned by the server for the ajax calls looks the way you think it does (no weird quotes or something). Try to do it with static pages. Etc.

Comment: script tags are being inserted into the returned php string by the php variables at the top of the code block. I've tried it both ways - with the script tags written in the string and via php variables. neither way works. seems strange that you say jquery .load doesn't strip out script tags as a LOT of people are experiencing this problem.

Comment: @Scott: Sorry, didn't realize `$tag1` and `$tag2` had the tags in them (the names should have been a clue). *"seems strange that you say jquery .load doesn't strip out script tags as a LOT of people are experiencing this problem"* I didn't just say it, I *demonstrated* it. Follow the link and you can see embedded script working just fine.

Comment: How DID you do it?! Please see original post edit for full details... S

Comment: @Scott: See update. Tried a couple of other things, but they're not it either. Good luck with it,

Comment: Thanks for the help - unfortunately can't vote up your answer as not enough 'reputation' yet! next time... :)

Answer (score 23):

Update now, which you can find on the jQuery doc site:

http://api.jquery.com/load/

It DOES strip tags only if you call load with a specific suffixed selector..

Script Execution

When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If .load() is called with a selector expression appended to the URL, however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated, and thus are not executed. An example of both cases can be seen below:

Here, any JavaScript loaded into #a as a part of the document will successfully execute.
1

```
$('#a').load('article.html');
```

However, in the following case, script blocks in the document being loaded into #b are stripped out and not executed:
1

```
$('#b').load('article.html #target');
```

Comment: Most complete answer I saw so far.

Answer (score 17):

This thread is a bit older now, but I found a workaround for the `$.load` + selector + `<script>` issue/feature which I would like to share. Maybe it will be helpful to someone. Instead of `$.load`, I use this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/some/url',
    success: function(html) {
        var content = $('<div />').html(html).find('#my-custom-selector');
        $('#container-to-place-html-in').html(content);
    }
});
```

Cheers, Alex

Comment: Very clever. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

Can you please confirm if it is stripping out the scripts or the event bind isn't working?
However, I think you can change the approach a little bit.
First  modify your script like

```
$("#titles_wrap").load("m_scripts/m_php/titles_loader.php", function(){
                                                                $..some code
                                                                $("[class^='title_send_']").click(function(){$("#title_php_loader").load("m_scripts/m_php/title_sender.php")});
                                                                });
```

Then remove the script part from php code

```
while($result_array = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            if($i2<=($titles_total)){

                $_SESSION['titles_string'] .= '<li id="listItem_'.$i2.'">

                                                <div id="titles_list_item">

                                                    <div id="titles_list_image_box" style="background-image: url(../../images/thumbs_test/'.$result_array[0].'); background-repeat: no-repeat; ">'.($i2+1).'</div>
                                                    <div id="title_php_loader"></div>
                                                        <div id="title_info_wrap">

                                                        <div id="title_current"><span class="title_current_grey" >current title: </span><br>'.$result_array[1].'
                                                            </div>

                                                                <div id="title_form_wrap">
                                                                    <span class="title_current_grey" >new title: </span><br><input name="title_input_'.$i2.'" id="title_input_'.$i2.'" type="text" class="title_input"></input>
                                                                    <div id="title_send" class="title_send_'.$i2.'">GO</div>
                                                                </div>

                                                            </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>';
                $i2++;
                                }
            }
```

Comment: ok, so you're also saying bind the click events after the content loads via the callback. Also, sorry if this is a real basic Q, but can you explain this for me... [class^='title_send_'] ...I don't understand the ^= operator - hoping this is something really useful i've never come across before! thanks for the help...

Comment: So what I think, when you paste response html to the page, it may be that html isn't ready so inline scripting isn't working (the same issue for which we use $(document).ready().)

Comment: And for `[class^='title_send_']` please check http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: thanks for the link re [class^='title_send_'] - v. useful!.. will definitely being using in the near future! Cheers, S

Comment: also, thanks for the thoughts re $(document).ready() - If you see the latest 'answer' I posted you'll see the original 'dilemma' has been resolved, however only in terms of functionality. I'll experiment with the $(document).ready() and post any news back here. - cheers for now. S

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use the callback function to bind the events rather than inlining it on your php page?

There might be a way to work around that but I wouldn't inline it in the first place which is why you're not finding others doing it. If you put binds in the callback they will attach when it's loaded.

Comment: yes, i get your point. but how can i add binds from the callback to an unknown number of elements with dynamcally generated selectors - i.e., $(".title_send_'.$i2.'")? Is it possible to do this after the content has loaded?

Comment: Ignore the dynamic class names and add a dummy class to the element that does nothing but identify it for your javascript. 
Like use  
** class="title_send_'.$i2.' dummyclass" ** 
then bind to .dummyclass and ignore the dynamic part.

Or if you don't like that, add a dummy class to the parent and then target the children of that parent with .children()

(You may want to check where you have id="title_send" in a loop because the id should be unique)

If you need to pass variables dynamically, try putting them inside alt or title tags and pulling them out using attr().

Comment: ok - seems like the way to go. I've reassigned unique id's in the php and gone for a consistent class. Will be working on this again later today - meetings this morning - but will report back once i get it working... thanks a lot for all the help so far! S

Answer (score -2):

It sucks I know but one thing you can do is write something like  within the html being loaded then after you .ajax or .load method in the callback do a string replace -> html = html.replace( /lscript/g, 'script' );

something to that effect should pulled the tag as an un-excuted tag.

hope that helps :)