# Jquery .load not loading javascript or flash

Tags: jquery, load, youtube

I am trying to load a page "/test/2" using Jquery into a div on the main page. I have 2 versions set up, one using iframes and the other using the jQuery load function. When I use the ajax load function the page's youtube portion (which I load using java-script) displays "You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video." ; however. when I use iFrames it loads perfectly.

Here is the code I'm using to load the page (using jquery):

> ```
> <script> $(document).ready(function(){
> $('#theList li a').click(function(){
>     $('#containerDiv').load($(this).attr('href'));
>     return false; 
> }); }); </script>
> ```

Here is the code I am using to load youtube on the page "/test/2" which is straight from youtube's API documentation.

```
<div id="ytapiplayer"> 
  You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.
</div> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
      // <![CDATA[

      // allowScriptAccess must be set to allow the Javascript from one 
      // domain to access the swf on the youtube domain
      var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always", bgcolor: "#cccccc" };
      // this sets the id of the object or embed tag to 'myytplayer'.
      // You then use this id to access the swf and make calls to the player's API
      var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
      swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/{{video.video_id}}?border=0&amp;autoplay=1;controls=0;hd=1;enablejsapi=1&amp;playerapiid=ytplayer",
                         "ytapiplayer", "680", "380", "8", null, null, params, atts);
      //]]>
    </script>
```

The weird thing is that it works perfectly with a normal youtube embed, and with iframes, but just not with a jQuery load function. Might I add that I am relatively new to jQuery, so there may be an issue with my load function that I am unaware of.

EDIT: This is what seems to cause the issue (i.e. I get an Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined). In the file I am trying to load, I have:

```
<script src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script> 
<script> google.load("swfobject", "2.1"); </script>
```

Which is needed to create the youtube object. Still unaware as to why it won't load.

Comment: Can you verify that the script is getting added to your div? Are there any javascript errors?

Comment: I get this error after the jQuery attempt - but according to chrome it seems to be getting all the data it needs from the .load      Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
(anonymous function):2
f.e.extend.globalEvaljquery.js:16
f.e.extend.globalEvaljquery.js:16
bmjquery.js:16
f.e.extend.eachjquery.js:16
f.fn.extend.domManipjquery.js:17
f.fn.extend.appendjquery.js:17
f.fn.extend.htmljquery.js:17
f.fn.extend.load.f.ajax.completejquery.js:18
f.extend._Deferred.e.resolveWithjquery.js:16
wjquery.js:18
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send.djquery.js:18

Comment: Thanks to this comment I was able to trace down the error. Thanks! I just ended up including the 2 files that seemed to cause the issue in my parent page - I'm assuming jQuery doesn't like it when you try to load from external sources? Anyway, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's load function will strip script tags..

see this related SO question [jquery load() strips script tags - workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036870/jquery-load-strips-script-tags-workaround)

Comment: Thank you, I was able to actually get around this by including the script loading in my parent page.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish this would be to use `get()` instead of `load()`, and to create the content in the `success` callback.  In this example, the server would just return the video id, not the div and script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#theList li a').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.get($(this).attr('href'), { }, function(data) {
            $('#containerDiv').append('<div id="ytapiplayer">You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.</div>');
            var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
            swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/" + data + "?border=0&amp;autoplay=1;controls=0;hd=1;enablejsapi=1&amp;playerapiid=ytplayer",
                     "ytapiplayer", "680", "380", "8", null, null, params, atts);
        });
    });
});
```