# Ajax - how to make every link/form on the page reload only part of that page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a website, and I want to keep part of it static. Now, in order to do that, I need to replace single div, something like that:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="contentToReplace">
    </div>
    <div id="myStaticContent">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, how can I catch all clicks on anchors and clicks on forms submit button, and reload `contentToReplace`? I tried using `jQuery.load()` and it was perfect, but it was not loading scripts, and I need those. Also, I don't know how to submit forms with ajax requests.

Answer (score 0):

To catch the `a` clicks and `input[type=submit]` clicks, you would do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a, input[type=submit]').on('click', function(e){
       // probably want to prevent default behavior
       e.preventDefault();

       // put the load stuff here

   });
}
```

As for the scripts not loading, you should check out the following SO:[jquery load() strips script tags - workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036870/jquery-load-strips-script-tags-workaround)