# Ajax and external JS scripts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Have the issue here when I dynamically load a php page the external JS file linked into that PHP pages doesn't seem to take effect. There is know JS code in the HTML file to call functions, the JS files does all the work by modifying certain tags.

HTML page will load the PHP file which is linked to the JS script. Relevant code below.

This does work if loaded directly, just not when loaded dynamically I've similar issues like this in the past where the solution was to use the call back feature when loading the content however since all the JS is in a external file not sure of the best method.

HTML code to load PHP file

```
<script>
   $(document).ready (function() {
      $('#test').click(function(event) {
        $('#content').empty();
        $('#content').load('view/search.php');
      })
    })
</script>
```

How the JS is linked into the PHP file

```
       <script type="text/javascript" src="edit.js"></script>
```

Again all the code works when loading the PHP page directly.

Many Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the path to `edit.js` is correct? The host page's URL will be used as the current directory, not `view/search.php`.

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036870/jquery-load-strips-script-tags-workaround.

Comment: Do you see `edit.js` being requested in your developer tools, or not being requested at all? Also, where is your `script` located in your `search.php` output? Maybe it's not getting included because of where it is in your markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading HTML containing script tags is supported. However, keep in mind that `load` will just insert your content into the DOM. Therefore, if you have a `<script src="edit.js"></script>` being inserted, the DOM will try to load `edit.js` from the current directory, not from the directory of the `php` file you're loading.

Answer (score 0):

make the php file output the content of edit.js in a script tag

e.g.

```
<script>
   <?php
      echo file_get_contents('edit.js');
   ?>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly this has worked for me. Then the js file is loaded when the click is made. The cons of this method is that if it is clicked multiple times, the file will load each time, cluttering your DOM which can result in a slow site.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready (function() {
      $('#test').click(function(event) {
        $('#content').empty();
        $('#content').load('view/search.php', function() {
               $.getScript(path+to+script);
        });
      })
    })
</script>
```