# materializecss slide-out effect stops with JQuery load()

Tags: jquery, html, css, materialize

I'm using materializecss to make a web page and thought about creating a "master page" using jQuery to avoid repeating (and correcting) the same thing across multiple pages. The problem appeared when I applied the following:

```
<header>
    <script>
        $().ready(function () {
            $("header").load("master.html");
        });
    </script>
</header>
```

And tried to bring a side nav that contains (this is all there so far is on master.html):

```
<nav>
    <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav fixed">
        <li><a href="index.html">Início</a></li>
        <li><a href="sobreSrd.html">Sobre os SRDs</a></li>
        <li><a href="noticias.html">Noticias</a></li>
        <li><a href="combinacoes.html">Combinações</a></li>
        <li><a href="filhotes.html">Filhotes</a></li>
        <li><a href="adote.html">Adote</a></li>
    </ul>

    <a id="mobButton" href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse">
        <i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i>
    </a>
</nav>
```

After researching, I've found out that jQuery's load method "strips away" the script from html (please correct me if I'm wrong). Some suggested loading the script again, but it didn't work. I think it has something to do with the data-activates property/attribute, but I can't find much information about it.

Has anyone had this issue? how did you solve it?

Comment: jQuery's `load()` method only strips scripts prior to execution if you include a suffixed selector expression (e.g., `load("master.html #header");`). That means, as long as you're loading without that expression, as you've specified, scripts will be executed before they're removed. Assuming the contents of "master.html" are consistent and correct, the problem is elsewhere. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6037060/603369 for a discussion and debugging help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. BUT THIS WORKS TO ME.

What I do? When a need to load html, I load again materialize css:

```
$("header").load("master.html", function () { jQuery.getScript("materialize.js"); });
```

Works! But... show this messagem in debug's console: ***Velocity is already loaded. You may be needlessly importing Velocity again; note that Materialize includes Velocity.***

To remove this, you can do that:

```
$("header").load("master.html", function () { 
    delete jQuery.Velocity;
    jQuery.getScript("materialize.js");
});
```

Then, no message apear in debug window. You ask me: "Performance? for destroy and instantiate $.Velocity" I answer: "I dont know"

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trials and tests and getting my peers involved into the issue. We noticed that the html file was loading only after the scripts that assigned events to the tags.

To fix this I changed the call to:

```
$("header").load("master.html", function () { /*code to execute*/ });
```

That allowed for the file to be loaded before any work to be done on it.
For more information: http://api.jquery.com/load/