# JavaScript not executing after JQuery table reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function that reloads a table for me, however when I click to reload  the table does not execute the JavaScript inside it. it does refresh tho. I am just temporarily using a h3 to click as it was easy.

```
<script>
        function RefreshTable()
         {
            $( "#calenderTable" ).load( "my-page.html #calenderTable" );
          }

        $(document).ready(function()
        {
          $("h3").click(function()
          {
            RefreshTable();
          });

        });
</script>
```

HTML is

```
  <h3>Refresh Table</h3>

                                     <table class="table" id="calenderTable">

                                        <tr>
                                            <th  scope="col">House</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Monday <br><script type="text/javascript">document.write("Hello World");</script></th>
                                            <th scope="col">Tuesday <br><script type="text/javascript">document.write(getDate(2));</script></th>
                                            <th scope="col">Wednsday <br><script type="text/javascript">document.write(getDate(3));</script></th>
                                            <th scope="col">Thursday <br><script type="text/javascript">document.write(getDate(4));</script></th>
                                            <th scope="col">Friday <br> <script type="text/javascript">document.write(getDate(5));</script></th>
                                        </tr>

                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="cal"><a href="#"> 1 </a></td>
                                            <td ></td>
                                            <td ></td>
                                            <td ></td>
                                            <td ></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

so the first time the page is loaded it displays "hello world" however when i click to refresh it no longer displays. I am just using hello world for this example, I really want the getDate function to execute and display the correct date in the table.

Comment: I am unable to see any `h3` tag in your given HTML

Comment: @AlivetoDie Thats not the problem tho, when i click it it does reload.

Comment: how can we check? Add that HTML too buddy

Comment: Ok I added the h3 and the table id too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery load() strips script tags - workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036870/jquery-load-strips-script-tags-workaround)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand

```
<script>
    function refreshTable() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'my-page.html',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (html) {
                $("#calenderTable").html($(html).find("#calenderTable").html());
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("h3").on('click', function () {
            refreshTable();
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: so for some reason that only loads the hello world and none of the table or page content, what i am trying to do is refresh a table and execute the script inside it.

Comment: The html code is probably invalid, is there 
<table><tr><th>content</th></tr></table> valid ?