# jQuery .load() function stripping out <img> tags from WordPress posts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image

I am having issues displaying images in a HTML div that loads dynamically using jQuery `.load()`. The jQuery function I am currently using is included below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    // Past sendout nav trigger function
    e( ".btn--nav-trigger" ).click(function() {
        e( this ).toggleClass( "btn--nav-trigger-active" );
        e( ".sendout__list" ).toggleClass( "sendout__list--open" );
    });

     // AJAX .load function for sendout post content
    e( ".sendout-link" ).click(function() {     
        e( ".btn--nav-trigger" ).toggleClass( "btn--nav-trigger-active" );
        e( ".sendout__list" ).toggleClass( "sendout__list--open" );
        var post_url = e( this ).attr( "href" );
        e( "#sendout-container" ).html( '<div class="loading"></div>' );
        e( "#sendout-container" ).load( post_url + "#sendout-content", function( response, status, xhr ) {
            if ( status == "error" ) {
                var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                e( "#sendout-container" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

The function successfully loads the text and YouTube iframe from the selected WordPress post, but it always strips the images.

The `href` attribute from the function is using `<?php the_permalink(); ?>` from WordPress. The individual posts load correctly, but something with the `.load()` function is stripping out the full `<img>` tags.

**Update**

It looks like the entire div that contains the image is being stripped as well. Not sure why this is happening. I have included the WordPress HTML/PHP code that is being fully stripped when using the `.load()` function below. This code is displayed correctly using WordPress/PHP.

```
<?php if(get_field( 'meme_one_image' )): ?>
<div class="sendout__row sendout--meme">
    <?php 
    $memeOneImage = get_field( 'meme_one_image' );
    if( !empty($memeOneImage) ): ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $memeOneImage['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $memeOneImage['alt']; ?>" />
        <div class="sendout--meme_share">
            <h4>Share this meme</h4>
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo $memeOneImage['url']; ?>" class="button">Facebook</a>
            <a href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=<?php echo $memeOneImage['title'] .' : '. $memeOneImage['url']; ?>" class="button">Twitter</a>
            <button class="button copy-button" data-clipboard-text="<?php echo $memeOneImage['url']; ?>">Copy URL</button>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Update Two**

I have fixed my theme files and JavaScript to use the correct elements to dynamically load the post type content block. I have updated my `.load();` function to implement the fixes suggest by Alexander O'Mara.

Images are loading now via `.load();`.

Comment: There is no reason this would happen. How are you establishing that the images are not there - because they don't show as images on the page, or have you actually verified that the img tags are not present in the output?

Comment: See if this answers your question which sounds similar  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036870/jquery-load-strips-script-tags-workaround

Comment: @Utkanos I have reviewed the rendered page and the source, and in both cases the full `<img>` is being stripped out of the jQuery loaded content. If I view the page that is loaded by WordPress/PHP, the images are not being stripped.

Comment: Just in case you weren't aware, WP sites have a [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) you can leverage to fetch parts of your content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, you are trying to load an entire HTML document inside another HTML document, which is really strange and likely error prone.

The [`jQuery.load` method](https://api.jquery.com/load/) is for loading HTML content and putting it inside another element. Typically that HTML content will contain only the content you want, not the full document with `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` tags.

As a solution, you may wish to use `jQuery.load`'s [fragment loading feature](https://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments) to specify the ID of an element within the page to use instead of the full document.

**Example:**

```js
e( "#sendout-container" ).load( post_url + ' #some-element-id', function( response, status, xhr ) {
```

---

Alternately you could use `jQuery.ajax` to load the HTML document and extract the HTML of the elements you want to use.

**Example:**

```js
$.ajax({
    // Example URL.
    url: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://example.com/'
}).done(function(data) {
    // Parse the HTML document.
    var doc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(data, 'text/html');

    // Select some content from the document.
    var body = $(doc).find('body').html();

    // Put that content in an element.
    $('#content').html(body);
});
```

```css
#content {
  border: solid black 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="content">
Loading...
</div>
```

Comment: I implemented the fragment loading feature, but images are still being stripped. I have the individual send out template loading from a WordPress template part. The template part only includes the necessary HTML and WP query. Do you have tips for swapping `.load()` for `.ajax`?

Comment: @MikeHermary I've added an example that uses `.ajax` to load the html, parse it into a new document, and select some contents from it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the Ajax code. I have tried implementing the code, but the same issues remain. For some reason images are being stripped. Do you know if WordPress has any conflicts with images being loaded via JavaScript?

Comment: @MikeHermary Not to my knowledge, there must be something else going on. I would double check that the image tags are in the AJAX response.

Comment: I think I have solved the problem. The issue seemed to be related to the theme file structure and how I was loading content via JavaScript. Using `.load()` is working in this implementation. Thanks for your assistance.